# Expected value function of an integrable random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Given $X$ an integrable random variable on $(\omega, \mathscr{F}, \mathscr{P})$ with distribution function $F_X$. Let $Z(w) = a(X(w))^2 + b$ where $a,\ b\in R$.  Prove, starting from simple functions, that $E(Z(w)) = a\int x^2dF_{X}(x) + b$

**My solution** If $Z$ is a simple random variable, then $Z = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\ 1_{A_i}$ ($a_i\in R$, $A_i$s are partitions of $ \omega$). Thus, $E(Z(X)) =\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_iE(1_{A_i}(X))=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_iP({X\in A_i})$ (since $Z(X)$ is a random variable) $=\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\int 1_{A_i}(x)dF_{X}(x) = \int z(x)dF_{X}(x) = \int ax^2dF_X(x) + bdF_{X}(x) = a\int x^2dF_X(x) + b$ (since $\int dF_X{x} = 1$ because $F_X$ is a distribution function of rv $X$).

Thus if $Z\geq 0$ and $\left\{Z_n\right\}$ are simple functions with $Z_n\uparrow Z$, then $Z(X)\uparrow Z(X)$, so $E(Z(X)) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} E(Z_n(X)) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a\int x^2dF_X(x) + b = a\int x^2dF_X(x) + b$ (by Monotone Convergence Theorem for expectations and integrals, respectively)

Finally, since $X$ is integrable, $Z(X)= aX^2+b$ is also integrable, so $E(Z(X)) = E(Z^{+}(X)) - E(Z^{-}(X)) = \int (aX^2+b)^{+}dF_{X}(x) - (aX^2+b)^{-}dF_X(x) = \int (ax^2+b)dF_{X}(x) = a\int x^2dF_X(x) + b$

**My question:** Could someone please help review my solution above? Particularly, for the last step, is $E(Z^{+}(X)) = \int (aX^2+b)^{+}dF_{X}(x)$ valid? My reasoning for this equation is because we could rewrite $E(Z(X)) =\int ZdF_X(x)$.

Comment: Nobody wants to help me with this problem?

Comment: A major objection is that there is no such thing as $Z(X)$ in the exercise since $Z=aX^2+b$. Relatedly, the whole passage where you assume that $Z$ is a simple random variable is offtopic since $Z$ is *given* to you by $Z=aX^2+b$ and there is no reason to assume that *this random variable* $Z$ is simple. Similar remark about the passage with "$\left\{Z_n\right\}$ are simple functions with $Z_n\uparrow Z$, then $Z(X)\uparrow Z(X)$".

Comment: Wait, so I have to start with $X$ is a simple random variable? Because the question asks to prove it by starting from simple functions, so that's why I assume. Could you please show me how you would do it?

Comment: The approximation you have to consider is the approximation of $f:x\mapsto ax^2+b$ by simple functions.

Comment: isn't that $f$ is Z in this case as $Z(X) = aX^2+b$?

Comment: No. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: so I should start with $X$ being a simple rv? But then when squaring the finite sum, we get a mess:(

Comment: No, you should start with $f$ being approximated by simple functions.

Comment: @Did: my apology for being dumb, but here's what I got from your hint: I tried approximating $f$ by simple functions $\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_k1_{A_k}$, so $E(f(x)) = E(ax^2+b) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_kE(1_{A_k}(x)) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kP(x\in A_k) = \int f(x)dF_{X}(x)= \int {ax^2+b}dF_{X}(x) = a\int x^2dF_{X}(x) + b$. Now, if $f\geq 0$ and $f_n$ are simple with $f_n\uparrow f$, then $f_n(x)\uparrow  f(x)$, so $E(f(x)) = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} E[f_n(x)] =  \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int f_n(x)dF_(X)(x) = \int f(x)dF_{X}(x) = a\int x^2dF_X(x) + b$.

Comment: Finally, since $X$ is integrable random variable, $f$ is also integrable and random variable. Thus, $E(f(X)) = E(f^{+}(X)) - E(f^{-}(X)) = \int f^{+}(x)dF_{X}(x) - \int f^{-}(x)dF_{X}(x) = \int f(x)dF_{X}(x)$ (Q.E.D) Is this proof correct?

Comment: @Did: could you help review my solution, based on your hint, in the last two comments above?