# Approximating $n$-step transition matrix as $n\rightarrow \infty$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Approximate the $n$-step transition matrix $P^n$ as $n$ gets very large, given the $4\times 4$ matrix $$P =\pmatrix{0.5 & 0.5 &  0 &  0 \\ 1 &  0 &  0 &  0 & \\ 0 &  0.5 &  0 &  0.5 & \\ 0 &  0 &  0 &  1}$$.

**My solution** I ran some calculations using Excel, and found that $P^n$ converges to the following matrix: $$\pmatrix{0.666 &  0.333 & 0 & 0 \\  0.666 & 0.333 & 0 & 0 \\  0.333 & 0.166 & 0 & 0.5 \\  0 & 0 & 0 & 1}.$$

**My question** Is there a systematic way to solve this problem or in general, for any given matrix $P$?

Comment: As you are not a newcomer in Math SE, I advise you to learn some of the basic rules for writing a matrix (look at the way I have edited them,knowing that there are other, more sophisticated, ways).

Comment: @JeanMarie: I appreciate your advise, and I would learn it.

Comment: "Is there a systematic way to solve this problem or in general, for any given matrix P?" There is, and this is basically what the first chapters of any textbook on finite Markov chains establish. Which one are you using?

Comment: @Did: I'm using Ross's A first course in Probability.

Btw, did you have a chance to help review my solution for the problem you gave me the hint? I meant this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1937862/expected-value-function-of-an-integrable-random-variable?noredirect=1#comment3980806_1937862

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [matriz diagonalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix#Diagonalization); this is representing some matrix $M$ as $M=PDP^{-1}$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix. The diagonal elements are necessarily the eigenvalues of $M$, and $P$ is a change of basis. In other words, the space on which $M$ acts admits a basis of eigenvalues, and in this basis $M$'s action has a particularly simple representation (simply multiply each eigenvector component by its corresponding eigenvalue).

In this form, it is easy to derive a formula for $M^n$, and you can easily check that we have $M^n=PD^nP^{-1}$ (where calculating $D^n$ is easy precisely because it is diagonal).

At that point, it's just a matter of taking the limit as $n\to \infty$. Wolfram Alpha can calculate an exact expression for the $n$-th power of your matrix ([here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B%5B1%2F2,1%2F2,0,0%5D,%5B1,0,0,0%5D,%5B0,1%2F2,0,1%2F2%5D,%5B0,0,0,1%5D%5D%5En)), and you can check that letting $n\to \infty$ the matrix becomes precisely that which you found empirically, where $0.666$, $0.333$ and $0.166$ are in fact $2/3$, $1/3$ and $1/6$ (respectively).

Comment: Many thanks for your help! I wonder why these values are nothing like the limiting probabilities though. Is it because this matrix does not represent an irreducible Markov chain?

Comment: I am sorry; what do you mean by limiting probabilities?

Comment: So you could interpret that matrix as transition probability matrix, and limiting probabilities is here: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~gravner/MAT135B/materials/ch15.pdf

Comment: Well, these values *are* the limiting probabilities, by definition, aren't they?

Comment: No. I computed the limiting probabilities (which is the solution of the equation: $\vec{\pi}P = \vec{\pi}$ and the result is $\vec{\pi} = [0,\ 0,\ 0,\ 1]$. I think the reason is

Comment: Notice that equation has multiple solutions. Any $\pi$ of the form $[2b,b,0,1-3b]$ for $0 \leq b \leq 1/3$ will work. Perhaps this makes the $P$-limit more familiar?

Comment: I tried diagonalizing $P$, and I got this one: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonalize+%7B%7B0.5,+0.5,+0,+0%7D,%7B1,0,0,0%7D,+%7B0,0.5,0,0.5%7D,+%7B0,0,0,1%7D%7D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45905/discussion-between-fimpellizieri-and-user177196).

Comment: @user177196 Again, "these values are the limiting probabilities", not "by definition", but by a theorem. (I find surprising that you accept nearly instantaneously this answer which, while technically correct, shuns every Markov chain aspect of the question. Why the tag (markov-chains) and not (linear-algebra) or (matrices), then? A lost opportunity to understand why the limit is what it is and how to compute it with no diagonalization and no simulation.)

Comment: @Did: what is the theorem u're talking about?

Comment: @user177196 Convergence in distribution of (finite) (ergodic) Markov chains to their (unique) stationary distribution.

Comment: But this is not unique because the markov chain here is not irreducible. The solution of $\vec{\pi}P=\vec{\pi}$ is not unique.